# Media Function Keys Randomly Disabled

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, spotify

Every now and then, my media keys (F7, F8, and F9) keep randomly stop working with Spotify. I don't have any other media apps open, like iTunes or anything, just Spotify. A program restart doesn't solve the problem, forcing me to restart the entire computer for it to work. How do I fix this?

Comment: Are you a Chrome user? What are the applications open while you are listening?

Comment: I generally have IDEs open, and Chrome. PyCharm, Atom, and Sublime. Sometimes chatting applications such as Discord and Slack.

Comment: Try restarting Chrome when you have the issue again in the future. Chrome often tries to utilize those keys for its own media control. I believe you can disable this somewhere in settings.

Comment: Fixed it, that worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like we were able to find the problem through the comments. Chrome sometimes "hijacks" your media buttons for its own functions. A quick google search yielded the following result:

> You can set to the keyboard shortcuts to work only when Chrome is in focus:
>
> - Open the Chrome app menu
>
>   - Select Tools > Extensions
>   - Click the ‘Keyboard Shortcuts’ link at the bottom of the page
>   - Find the Google Play Music section
>   - Change any specified media key options from ‘Global’ to ‘In Chrome’
>   - Fix Media Key Hijacking in Chrome
>       [image: image with keyboard shortcuts]
>
> Or you can disable/remove the app/extension from Chrome entirely:
>
> - Open the Chrome app menu
> - Select Tools > Extensions
> - Find ‘Google Play Music’
> - Uncheck the ‘Enabled’ box OR click the trash can to remove
>
> [image: image deleting extension]

**Source:** [OMGChrome](https://www.omgchrome.com/chrome-google-music-media-keys/)